# how to list all unanswerd questions use laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I have 3 table    which is

```
  user_answer          table==>   id  qid          content 
  user_question        table==>   id  title 
  user_question_count  table=>    id  answer_num
```

#### UserAnswer Model:

```
      public function question()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserQuestion', 'id', 'qid');
    }
```

#### UserQuestion Model

```
 public function counts()
  {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserQuestionCount', 'id', 'id');
  }


  public function answer()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAnswer', 'qid', 'id');
   }
```

I want list all  unanswered question use laravel relation model , unanswered question don't have record in UserQuestionCount table and UserAnswer table , how to realize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$questions = UserQuestion::doesntHave('answer')->get();
```

`whereHas` and `doesntHave` are made to check if a model has or doesn't have a relationship linked to it.

The documentation is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) if you scroll down a bit.

By the way, you should name your relationship `answers` and not `answer` since it's a One to Many.

Answer (score 1):

if Question hasMany Answers, Answer belongsTo question:

**UserQuestion:**

```
 public function answers()
 {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAnswer', 'qid', 'id');
 }
```

**UserAnswer:**

```
   public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserQuestion','qid','id'); 
    }
```

And you are looking for [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).
then,

```
$questions=UserQuestion::doesntHave('answers')->get();
```

Comment: `doesntHave` is enough if he doesn't need to make a custom query.

Comment: @陈孝右 you're welcome. i hope you understood about relationship setups too.